# Set radrating value for multiple items within Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, radgrid

I'm trying to put radrating control within RadGrid control for multiple items. This is what I have currently:

```
       <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid2_ItemDataBound" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid2_NeedDataSource">
            <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="False">
            </ClientSettings>
            <MasterTableView>                                      
                    <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
                </RowIndicatorColumn>
                <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Property.PropertyName" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" DataFormatString="{0:g}" HeaderText="Property" SortExpression="Property.PropertyName">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>     
                     <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TestimonialHtml" DataFormatString="{0:g}" HeaderText="Review" SortExpression="TestimonialHtml">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>                           
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TestimonialDate" DataFormatString="{0:g}" HeaderText="Review Date" SortExpression="TestimonialDate">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>   
                      <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Task" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadRating runat="server" ID="TestimonialRating" Value="RatingHelper" Precision="Half"></telerik:RadRating>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>                                               
                          </Columns>                 
            </MasterTableView>               
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

While the gridboundcolumns are working fine, the radrating control doesn't want to accept the RatingHelper value and I'm getting this error:

> Cannot create an object of type 'System.Decimal' from its string
> representation 'RatingHelper' for the 'Value' property.

What should I change to make this work?

Comment: "Value" is a double, so why would it accept the string literal "RatingHelper"?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-accessing-cells-and-rows.html. See how to access the rating in the OnItemDataBound event so you can set its value as needed. Direct binding in the markup is not going to work like this, as McGarnagle noted.

Another option is to use Eval() statements like shown here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/rating/examples/gridrating/defaultcs.aspx.